# Apple's javascript MusicKit API authorize in electron app

Tags: javascript, oauth, electron, appauth, apple-musickit

I wanted to make an electron app that uses [Apple's MusicKitjs API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/musickitjs). However, the authorize function opens another window. This causes problems with electron since each window is sandboxed. The authentication does not seem to be OAuth which rules out a tool like [AppAuth-JS](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-JS).

Any ideas on how to implement non-OAuth API authentication in electron?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best answer I can come up with so far is to not use Electron. Use NW.js instead.

There may be a way to make MusicKit.js work with Electron, but it will likely compromise security or require substantial effort.

NW.js does not have the same problem since it is a single process framework. When authorizing the MusicKit instance, it pops up a 2nd window and allows the user to login as desired. However, NW.js does need [proprietary codecs](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Developers/Enable%20Proprietary%20Codecs/) to play audio from MusicKit. I am using [these prebuilts](https://github.com/iteufel/nwjs-ffmpeg-prebuilt) and it seems to work fine so far.

Comment: I'm getting a Cross-Origin Request Blocked error in the Chromium blogs when I try to auth to musickit in an NW.js app - did you see anything like that? Tried the steps here to no avail: http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Security%20in%20NW.js/

Comment: No, I did not run into any problems like that. Although, I abandoned that project after Apple released a web client for Apple Music. So, it's been a while since worked with it.